# Cannot specialize fnc

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Having those:

```
template<class T>
struct Is_Node
{
    enum {value = false};
};

template<class Key_T, class Value_T>
class Node;//frwd decl.

template<class K,class V>
struct Is_Node<Node<K,V>>
{
    enum {value = true};
};

enum Tags {tree_tag,node_tag,root_tag,parent_tag,left_tag,right_tag,key_tag,value_tag,color_tag};

template<Tags>
struct Tag_2_Type
{/*eb*/};

template<class Node_T>
typename Node_T::node_ptr& get_root(Node_T& node)
{
    return get_root_hlp(node,Tag_2_Type<Is_Node<Node_T>::value>());
}

template<class Node_T>
typename Node_T::node_ptr& get_root_hlp(Node_T& node,Tag_2_Type<node_tag>)
{
    return node->root_;
}

template<class Node_T>
typename Node_T::node_ptr& get_root_hlp(Node_T& node,Tag_2_Type<tree_tag>)
{
    return node->root_;
}
```

I'm getting error:
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'Node_T &get_root(Node_T &)'

Any idea why?

Comment: Which line the error is coming ? Which code `get_root()` is specialized ?

Comment: That error message seems to be inconsistent with the code. In the code get_root() doesn't return Node_T&, but Node_T::node_ptr&. Probably the compiler doesn't see a node_ptr inside the type you use as the Node_T parameter of get_root.

Comment: please provide a full test case, the code is incomplete. At least IsNode is a specialization of a template not shown there. Also I cannot see any attempted specialization of get_root that the compiler might complain about.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough code to know for certain, but I suspect the problem is that you haven't defined Node when you try to call get_root, so the compiler doesn't recognise Node_T::node_ptr. Another problem appears to be that get_root calls get_root_hlp before it's declared.